# Workflows not triggering in SharePoint Online, WF Health showing Suspended

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

Site workflow status showing: **Workflows are suspended** as shown in images.
What happened

---

1. A workflow was showing around 1574 suspended tasks, I removed that workflow
2. Then I created a new workflow associated with some other list, whenever I try to run it manually a popup messages shows **"Something went wrong. To try again, reload the page and then start the workflow."**
3. Tried a Powershell to terminate all the suspended workflows but it shows `Error terminating workflow on  245  Error Details: Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Scope '/spo/cf92019c-152d-42f6-bbcc-0cf96e6b0108/a0fa543e-3fd7-4128-9e0e-a57639ce86ea/279d896b-5ac1-4c4c-bf
   f0-530822070d49' is not in an active state. Its current state is 'Suspended'. HTTP headers received from the server - ActivityId: 8d7ec475-cfe3-4dc3-b00a-b91eb0a490b8. NodeId: . Scope: . Client ActivityId : 414c4b9
   f-2012-0000-451a-8c2bc9172cd0."`

[image: Site]